# kendo dataSource.update() API, not dataSource.sync()

Tags: api, kendo-ui, listbox, crud

I would like to fire transport.update() via API on click.

```js
$("#save-changes-btn").kendoButton({
          click: function (e) {
            dataSource.sync();
          }
      });
```

But when there is no event, sync () update is not executed. If there are several changes, update is executed several times.
I would like update should only be executed once.

A possible solution would be a function similar to dataSource.read (). However, this is only available as sync() for update, destroy, and create.

dataSource.transport.update(); Update is runing, but in 
'update: function (e){ e.success();}' e is undefined.

How can I fire per click update so that update is always executed once per click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable batch operations for the dataSource instance. In this way all updated records will be submitted in bulk, as an array.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-batch

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing

Note that updated, deleted and new records will always be submitted separately.

Comment: batch: true, it dosen't  works for once update fireing with kendoListBox.
With the Grid's it works fine...